# How is the Action Bar hidden here?

Tags: android

I'm looking at the demo app of [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/tree/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesignDemo).

In its [manifest](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesignDemo/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), it uses the `AppTheme`

`<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

The `AppTheme` is simply `Theme.Light`

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

However, if I use the same theme in my app, I get an Action Bar but not in theirs (both using the layout renderer and the emulator). Does anyone know how they manage to hide the Action Bar?

Thanks

**EDIT** Here's my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="148dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:background="#01579b"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="104dp" android:id="@+id/">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:text="MaterialDesign"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="25dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
                android:background="#88CECECE" />

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloatSmall
                android:id="@+id/buttonColorSelector"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
                android:background="#1E88E5"
                materialdesign:iconDrawable="@drawable/icn_select_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tagapp.tagapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.grade:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module build.grade:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tagapp.tagapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Here's what the renderer shows when the demo app is loaded

[image]

There's no Action Bar in the layout renderer for their app, but there is for mine - even with `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` set. Here's mine:

[image]

Comment: by getting instance of actionbar in activity and hiding it there?

Comment: I can't see that happening in the [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesignDemo/src/main/java/com/gc/materialdesigndemo/ui/MainActivity.java) though.

Comment: Could you please post your relevant code? For example, your MainActivity.java?

Comment: They never created an ActionBar, so they do not need to hide it. In line 30: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); try this.

Comment: Looks pretty strange, so I just created a new project to do some tests. adding requestWindowFeatures(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) in the onCreate as first line does remove the TitleBar for me. https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesignDemo/src/main/java/com/gc/materialdesigndemo/ui/MainActivity.java#L30

Comment: Oh, sorry. I must have added it wrong before. Still, even with it in onCreate(), the bar shows up in the layout renderer when I load up mine but not theirs. I've added a capture.

Comment: can you post your manifest and gradle.build please? I did copy your entire code and do not have an actionbar there :D

Comment: I've added them now. The thing is that I don't get the action bar in the compiled app, but it shows up in the layout renderer which is strange because there's no action bar in the layout renderer for the demo app. The renderer doesn't interpret what's inside onCreate(), right?

Comment: okay, I see.. in my example I do not see the actionbar. Maybe you need to set the correct theme in the renderer

Comment: I'm already using the project's `AppTheme` in the renderer. One thing though, is the renderer supposed to interpret `requestWindowFeatures(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` specified in `onCreate()` though? Isn't it a run-time thing? If so, the renderer wouldn't be able to tell if the action bar has been "disabled".

Comment: this is for the titlebar and not the actionbar. you can associate the layout with an activity by adding tools:context=".MainActivity" to the rootlayout element

Comment: But are you saying that you don't see the Action Bar in the renderer for my code? I've pasted what I'm seeing in my renderer in my question now. Do you not see that though?

Comment: yes exactly! I only get the titlebar, but no actionbar

Comment: Ah. Could the title bar be removed too? It seems like they've managed to hide / shrink it with some obscure method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in API 21

```
 this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Doesn't work .

Try to Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Or add this

```
 this.getActionBar().hide();
```

in onCreate method after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: I'm actually using API 22. The thing is that they don't seem to have these lines, but their bar doesn't show up in the layout renderer. For me, even with `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` set, it shows up in the renderer.